# Am I keeping references of selectors and targets/delegates correctly?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, selector

I've made my own custom photo gallery control, where the user can tap a photo to be taken to a larger version, or any other action you want.

I want this done so that the UIViewController holding this gallery contains the selectors, e.g

```
- (IBAction)photoThumbnailClicked(id)sender
{
    // Enlarge the photo here
}
```

I'd want to somehow keep a reference of the view controller and selector in the photo gallery object, so when each photo thumbnail button is generated, the targets can be set like this:

```
[thumbnail addTarget:self.target
                   action:self.action
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I'm currently keeping the references like this, although I'm not sure it's the best way as I have reason to believe there may be memory issues:

**PhotoGallery.h:**

```
@interface PhotoGallery : UIScrollView

@property UIViewController *target;
@property SEL action;

- (void)setTarget:(UIViewController*)viewController
     withAction:(SEL)action;
@end
```

**setTarget method in PhotoGallery.m:**

```
- (void)setTarget:(UIViewController*)target withAction:(SEL)action
{
    self.target = target;
    self.action = action;
}
```

Is this the best way of doing this? If not, what should I do instead?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it possible that `target` could be an instance of whatever a `PhotoGallery` instance is added to?

Comment: That's the idea, the "target" is currently the reference to the UIViewController containing the gallery. The "action" is the selector in the UIViewController which is called when a thumbnail is tapped. Is this the best way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I've assumed ARC*

**IF** your view hierarchy looks like this:

```
someViewControllerOrView   <------------|
       -                                |
  <any number of views>                 |
            -                           |
        photoGalleryInstance            |
                             -target ----
```

Then you probably want your `target` to be a weak reference otherwise you will probably encounter a "retain cycle". That is `someViewController` holds on to `photoGalleryInstance` and `photoGalleryInstance` holds on to `someViewController` and neither is ever released.

```
@property (weak) UIViewController *target;
//or @property (unsafe_unretained) UIViewController *target; if target is < 5.0
```

Otherwise, your code looks like the standard way of implementing this pattern.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated! Also yeah, I'm using ARC, sorry I didn't specify that!